# SSL Configuration issue in AEM6

Tags: ssl, aem

I am having issues in configuring my AEM instance SSL configured. I am using below command to generate the keystore.

```
user@user/media/vivek/Misc/SelfWork/Author/ssl$ keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -validity 3650 -alias cqse -keystore /Misc/SelfWork/Author/ssl/cqkeystore.keystore -keypass password -storepass password -dname "CN=sbroders-w7, OU=CQ, O=Adobe, L=Ottawa,S=Ontario, C=CA"

/media/user/Misc/SelfWork/Author/ssl$ keytool -export -alias cqse -file client.cer -keystore cqkeystore.keystore 
/media/user/Misc/SelfWork/Author/ssl$ keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias cqse -file client.cer -keystore truststore.ts
```

This generate the keystore & truststore at /media/vivek/Misc/SelfWork/Author/ssl with name of cqkeystore.keystore. But when i start the AEM, No Error in err.log. What i can see relevant is

```
:25.01.2015 20:39:08.794 *INFO* [CM Configuration Updater (ManagedService Update: pid=[org.apache.felix.http])] org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector Started SslSelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8558
25.01.2015 20:39:08.794 *INFO* [CM Configuration Updater (ManagedService Update: pid=[org.apache.felix.http])] org.apache.felix.http.jetty Started Jetty 8.1.14.v20131031 at port(s) HTTP:8588 HTTPS:8558 on context path /
```

Below is my configuration details(httpd.config) on felix. On restart its runs only on http & not on https.

```
org.apache.felix.https.keystore.password="password"
org.apache.felix.http.session.timeout=I"0"
org.apache.felix.https.clientcertificate="none"
org.apache.felix.http.host="0.0.0.0"
org.apache.felix.http.debug=B"false"
org.apache.felix.https.jetty.cipersuites.included=[""]
org.apache.felix.https.truststore="/media/user/Misc/SelfWork/Author/ssl/truststore.ts"
org.apache.felix.http.context_path="/"
org.apache.felix.http.jetty.maxFormSize=I"204800"
org.apache.felix.http.jetty.requestBufferSize=I"8192"
org.apache.felix.https.keystore="/media/user/Misc/SelfWork/Author/ssl/cqkeystore.keystore"
org.apache.felix.https.nio=B"true"
org.apache.felix.http.jetty.responseBufferSize=I"24576"
org.apache.felix.http.jetty.headerBufferSize=I"16384"
org.apache.felix.https.enable=B"true"
org.osgi.service.http.port=I"8588"
org.apache.felix.http.enable=B"true"
org.apache.felix.http.mbeans=B"false"
org.osgi.service.http.port.secure=I"8558"
service.pid="org.apache.felix.http"
org.apache.felix.https.truststore.password="password"
org.apache.felix.http.nio=B"true"
org.apache.felix.https.keystore.key.password="password"
org.apache.felix.http.timeout=I"60000"
org.apache.felix.https.jetty.cipersuites.excluded=[""]
org.apache.felix.http.path_exclusions=["/system"]
```

Any suggestion how to resolve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below configuration worked for me,

```
org.apache.felix.https.keystore.key.password="password"
service.pid="org.apache.felix.http"
org.apache.felix.https.nio=B"true"
org.apache.felix.https.keystore.key="cqse"
org.apache.felix.https.keystore.password="password"
org.apache.felix.https.keystore="crx-quickstart/conf/cqkeystore.keystore"
org.osgi.service.http.port.secure=L"5433"
org.apache.felix.https.enable=B"true"
```

Steps i followed as per the documentation : [Enable SSL on Author](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/deploy/configuring/config-ssl.html#Enable%20SSL%20on%20the%20Author%20Instance)

And used this command to create keystore : `user@user-Aspire:/media/user/Misc/SelfWork/Author/crx-quickstart/conf$ keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -validity 3650 -alias cqse -keystore cqkeystore.keystore -keypass password -storepass password -dname "CN=sbroders-w7, OU=CQ, O=Adobe, L=Ottawa, S=Ontario, C=CA"`

Comment: Here is the detailed blog : http://vivekdhimaan.blogspot.in/2015/02/enable-ssl-in-aem6.html

Comment: Also undocumented property org.apache.felix.https.keystore.type might help.

Comment: And just to save people some headache, if you're trying different key/certificates I've found that changing the key alias en aem is just not enough. You also need to delete the previous key from the keystore. I assume it's some sort of cache issue, which I otherwise couldn't work around.